# Leaky shut off valve to toilet need to know what kind of sealant to use can't turn off Main water

Tags: toilet, valve

I can't afford a plumber at this time and the valve is leaking so badly it floods the bathroom. And somehow the main shut off is not working either. My house has been vandalized which is why I believe this is problem.

I really need some kind of help can somebody answer me please thank you

Comment: call the city hall and have the water to the property shut off

Comment: maybe the main shut-off is not the one that you think

Comment: the main shutoff works. doesn't mean it's not a bear and a half to turn off after decades. in terms of stopping the flow to the little fill pipe: you can temporarily freeze it with a can of dust-off to stop the flow w/o a valve.

Comment: A picture or two would help us to help you.

Comment: what is actually leaking, the valve itself or the connection to the valve?

Answer (score 1):

Dry ice on the pipe to freeze it so you can replace the valve has worked for me in the past. Pack 2-3" of dry ice around the supply or main line if you can access the smaller line to the toilet 1" would work. Turn on a cold water tap after several minutes to relieve pressure and verify there is no water flow. Once pipe is frozen replace valve, remove dry ice and you will be good to go. Use gloves with dry ice or instant frost bite will ocour if handled with bare skin.